# VersionOne: C# where to find VersionOne.SDK.APIClient that contains V1OAuth2APIConnector?

Tags: c#, versionone, oauth2client

I'm trying to access VersionOne using VersionOne.SDK.APIClient and OAuth2Client.
I was able to create a client_secrets.json and stored_credentials.json

I may not be using the right version of one of VersionOne.SDK.APIClient since it does not contain this V1OAuth2APIConnector..

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.APIClient).  [This file](https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.NET.APIClient/blob/master/APIClient/V1Oauth2APIConnector.cs) contains the `V1OAuth2APIConnector` class.

According to the source, `V1OAuth2APIConnector` is in the `VersionOne.SDK.APIClient` namespace.  If you can't find it there, then you're using the wrong version of the SDK and need to update.

Comment: Where is a compiled version of this SDK that contains V1OAuth2APIConnector ?

Comment: `V1OAuth2APIConnector` is new content that hasn't been rolled into the NuGet package yet.  You have to download the source from github and build the library yourself.  Just do a git clone, open the project and build it.